# What is the difference between .onAppear() and .task() in SwiftUI 3?

Tags: swift, swiftui

It seems we can now perform same task within [`onAppear(action:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onAppear(perform:)) or [`task(priority:action:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) in iOS 15. However, I could not find the advantage of [`task(priority:action:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) over [`onAppear(action:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onAppear(perform:)). Can anyone out there explain?

Comment: Which `.task()` are you referring to? Could you please link its documentation? I could only find it on `AnyView`.

Comment: see this article : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-an-asynchronous-task-when-a-view-is-shown
main thing is The task will be cancelled when this view disappears and allowing you to start asynchronous work as soon as the view is shown

Comment: @Alexander he is talking about this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/emptyview/task(_:)

Comment: Note also that `'task(priority:_:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer`

Answer (score 28):

Both [`task()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/defaultsharelinklabel/task(id:priority:_:)) and `onAppear()` are the same for running synchronous functions when a view appears.

The **main** point difference is in the [`task(id:priority:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/defaultsharelinklabel/task(id:priority:_:)) task will be **cancelled** when this **view disappears.** It means when you're calling any webservice/ API or added any other task and back the screen then this task will automatically cancel.

Task is executed **asynchronously** and allowing you to start **asynchronous work** as soon as the view is shown.

Another use of task is, you can use [`task(id:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/defaultsharelinklabel/task(id:priority:_:))
as mention in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/emptyview/task(id:_:))

> The running task will be cancelled either when the value changes causing a new task to start or when this view disappears.

> The example below shows listening to notifications to show when a user signs in.

```
Text(status ?? "Signed Out")
    .task(id: server) {
        let sequence = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(
            of: .didChangeStatus, on: server)
        for try await notification in sequence {
            status = notification.userInfo["status"] as? String
        }
    }
```

You can read more from [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-an-asynchronous-task-when-a-view-is-shown) article.

Answer (score 2):

`.task` combines `.onAppear`, `.onChange`, `.onDisappear` and the new `Concurrency`.

It runs when the view appears, it can cancel `Task` when it it disappears and if you use `.task(id:)` it will run again when the `id` changes.

And it can run `async await` code.

Answer (score 0):

- Task is the preferred way to run asynchronous code in SwiftUI, as it provides better control and ensures that the task is executed only once.Task will be executed when the view appears, and it will be automatically cancelled when the view disappears.
- OnAppear is useful modifier for simple tasks and view updates, but it is not ideal for asynchronous work.

Please check this small blog for detail information - https://medium.com/@heena.nvr/difference-between-task-onappear-b62a6ae967b7